# Example Application of FasterCSV

Tags: ruby, csv, fastercsv

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and web programming as well. Can someone show me some example of FasterCSV implementation.

Comment: Note that if you are using Ruby 1.9 the FasterCSV library is [built into the Ruby standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html). You only should use FasterCSV if you're using Ruby 1.8.x

Comment: I'm a bit confused bcoz you said that I should use FasterCSV if I'm using 1.8.x. What will I use if I'm using Ruby 1.9?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [FasterCSV examples folder](https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv/tree/master/examples) provides several examples.

PS. Please note that FasterCSV has nothing to do with Rails *framework*. Is a *Ruby library*.